# fermats little theorem by group theory

Tags: abstract-algebra

i was reading a proof on fermats little theorem by graph theory so the proof goes like this at first we prove G:Z/PZ-0 is a group under modulo multiplication

then we assume let g belong to G
By Bezout lemma there exists x,y  S.T gcd(g,p)=1
             gx +py=1
   implies gx=1mod(p)

next we create a sub group H  from G from a integer b in G, Such that H={b,b^2,b^3....,b^k} where k is order of b. Now my doubt is how do we know there exists a finite k
My proof:
we create p-1 equations from bx=1mod(p) by multiplying b on both sides

b^2x=bmod(p) and so on till b^px=b^(p-1)modp

now since there are p equations and p-1 modulo of p .we know at least one of them should be 1 because I started the equations from 1 modulo p.so for repeatition it should reach 1.

and then we get (b^k+1)x=1mod p

implying (b^k)*(bx)=1modp which implies b^k=1modp

is this proof right?? if not how can we be sure there is a finite order of element b

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$G$ is finite of order $p$, hence in the multiplicative group of nonzero elements $G^*$, by Lagrange's theorem, every element has order dividing $p-1$.

Comment: Thanks  i got it.